# c++ Inheritance Basics in Qt

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I wanted to extend a class with an additional property and then assign a base class object to this new class. Here is my sample code:

```
class QExtFileInfoList: public QFileInfoList
{
  public:
    bool newProperty;
}
QDir var1 = "/abc/def";
QFileInfoList var2 = var1.entryInfoList();     // works
QExtFileInfoList var3 = var1.entryInfoList();  // does not work
```

the code returns:

```
conversion from 'QFileInfoList {aka QList<FileInfo>}' 
      to non-scalar type 'QElfFileInfoList' requested
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: and what does `entryInfoList` return?

Comment: It returns a `QFileInfoList` by value. `QFileInfoList QDir::entryInfoList(Filters filters = NoFilter, SortFlags sort = NoSort) const`

Answer (score 0):

you have defined a new class. But who is creating them?
QDir will not create classes for you that you have created.

There are 3 solutions in mind:

1. write a converter function QFileInfoList to QElfFileInfoList
2. write a constructor for QElfFileInfoList taking just a QFileInfoList reference ( this would convert automatically if you would ask for conversion of a single instance)
3. derive a new class from QDir that is creating your own class for you.

I would choose them in these order.